# SQS set different ttl for each message

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

I came across SQS limitation and can't find a workaround. I have 2 queues, and I need messages to be moved from first queue to second if they were not processed during a certain period of time which is different for each message. My initial thought was to implement this with the help of DLQ, but from what I understand you can set retention period only for the queue, not for individual message. Maybe someone had the same issue and knows how to implement this?

Comment: Retention period is certainly the wrong tool, that will just delete the messages after a given time. Instead you should have altering for old messages and maybe a DLQ / redrive policy which moves the messages after a number of processing attempts.

Comment: @luk2302, the problem is that I need to move them without processing, the queue with  ttl for messages represents tasks for spot instances, where ttl is how long we are ready to wait for spot instance to become available. So if we couldn't get one in specified period of time, messages have to go to on-demand queue where they will be processed for sure.